# Pods/Eureka/Source/Core/Section.swift:291:127: Use of undeclared type 'Iterator'

Tags: swift, xcode

When i build the app for testing errors showing ,

```
/Pods/Eureka/Source/Core/Section.swift:291:127: Use of undeclared type 'Iterator'
/Pods/Eureka/Source/Core/Section.swift:291:54: Use of undeclared type 'Index'
/Pods/Eureka/Source/Core/Section.swift:303:20: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

This is where the error is referring :-

```
 public func replaceSubrange<C>(_ subrange: Range<Index>, with newElements: C) where C : Collection, C.Iterator.Element == Iterator.Element {
        for i in subrange.lowerBound..<subrange.upperBound {
            if let row = kvoWrapper.rows.object(at: i) as? BaseRow {
                row.willBeRemovedFromSection()
                kvoWrapper._allRows.remove(at: kvoWrapper._allRows.index(of: row)!)
            }
        }

        let range = NSRange(location: subrange.lowerBound, length: subrange.upperBound - subrange.lowerBound)
        kvoWrapper.rows.replaceObjects(in: range, withObjectsFrom: newElements.map { $0 })

        kvoWrapper._allRows.insert(contentsOf: newElements, at: indexForInsertion(at: subrange.lowerBound))
        for row in newElements {
            row.wasAddedTo(section: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Are you using Swift 4?

Comment: @AndrasM. Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1) i am using xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Comment: Just asking because the Eureka readme.md tells they require swift 4 and XCode 9 in their latest version. If you are using older XCode/Swift you need to load the appropriate version in your Podfile

Comment: @Andras M. I am upgrading xcode once it finish i will try then give u feedback . Thanks